# fetch excel column headers like A,B... in listbox of window form by using visual c#

Tags: c#, excel

i have made an excel COM Add-in for sending sms. in this i made a window form in which there is a listbox. i want to use excel columns like A,B,C.... as such in listbox list, though which i can read all contents of a particular column of excel. here i dont want to write code for a particular file. i want that when user open excel , my plugin should work with active workbook. please help me how to do that. please give me some coding examples which can i implement in my plugin. really need for help.please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i am replying on my own question. this answer is very helpful for this question.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet activeSheet =
    (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

    Excel.Range firstColumn = activeSheet.UsedRange.Columns["A", System.Type.Missing];

    firstColumn.Select();
```

Comment: anyone have query regarding this question can ask to me here.